# ¿Como pasar una variable de javascript a una variable php?

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que quiero es que mi variable de php obtenga el valor de mi variable de javascript

Asi obtengo mi valor de javascript:

```
    (function() {

var variable="contenido";
alert(variable);

})();

</script>
```

Asi quiero pasarlo a mi variable de php:

```
$url = "<script> document.write(variable) </script>";
echo 'variablePHP = '.$url;
```

Comment: Puede que haya alguna manera *sucia*  de hacerlo. Pero no es recomendable y podría ser peligroso. Es importante entender que Javascript se ejecuta del lado del cliente (navegador), mientras que PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor. Suponte que sea permitido ejecutar código desde el cliente en el servidor, y alguien escribe en el cliente código que borra archivos del servidor, o que revela las contraseñas de acceso o algo así... Generalmente para pasar datos de Javascript al servidor se suele usar Ajax, es una manera segura de hacerlo, ya que los datos se envían por medio de un archivo PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema ocurre por qué tu variable no es global por lo cual php no la encuentra, debes de declarar tu variable de manera global. Te comparto un ejemplo de pasar valores mediante cookies.

```js
<script> 
var variable = "";
(function() {

this.variable="contenido";
alert(this.variable);

})();

/*Ejemplo mediante cookiees*/
document.cookie = "lastname=Martinez";
</script>

<?php
$url = "<script> document.write(variable) </script>";
echo 'variablePHP = '.$url;

/*Ejemplo mediante cookies*/
$last_name = $_COOKIE['lastname'];
echo "Apellido".$last_name;
?>
```

Comment: Hola, intenté usar variables así como lo hiciste y no me lo permitió. Con cookies SÍ pude pero esta muy raro, tardan mucho en cambiar los valores, y no se como puedo hacer para que mi variable que quiero pasar, pueda ingresarle su dato al cookie